# Confusion about taking arbitrary element from $\langle a^k \rangle$ to prove $\langle a^k \rangle=\langle a^{gcd(n,k)} \rangle$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

> **Problem:** Let $a$ be an element of order $n$ in a group and let $k$ be a positive integer. Then $\langle a^k \rangle = \langle a^{gcd(n,k)}\rangle$.

**My proof:** Let $d=gcd(n,k)$, so there exist $r ∈ ℤ $ s.t $k=dr$. Suppose $a^{ki} \in \langle a^k \rangle$. We have $a^{ki} = a^{dri}= (a^d)^{ri} ∈ \langle a^d \rangle$. Thus $\langle a^k \rangle \subseteq \langle a^d \rangle $. For other inclusion, assume $a^{dj} ∈ \langle a^d \rangle$. We see $a^{dj} = a^{jpn+jqk}= (a^k)^{jq} ∈ \langle a^k \rangle$ for some $p,q \in \mathbb Z$. So $\langle a^d \rangle \subseteq \langle a^k \rangle$.

**Proof in the book:** Let $d=gcd(n,k)$ and let $k=dr$. Since $a^k = (a^d)^r$, we have by closure that $\langle a^k \rangle ⊆ \langle a^d \rangle$. By gcd theorem there are integers $s $ ans $t$ s.t $d=na+tk$. So $a^d= a^{ns+tk}=a^{ns}a^{tk} = (a^k)^t \in \langle a^k \rangle$ . This proves $\langle a^d \rangle \subseteq \langle a^k \rangle$.

**My confusion:** Is my proof correct? Because I used arbitrary element to show each is subset of other. On the other hand author used arbitrary element.

Comment: If $a^k \in \langle a^d \rangle,$ every power of $a^k$ is also in $\langle a^d \rangle,$ so this is enough to show that $\langle a^k \rangle \subseteq \langle a^d \rangle.$

Comment: If $G$ is a group, $H\leq G$ a subgroup, $S\subseteq G$ a subset, then pretty much by definition of a generated subgroup, $S\subseteq H$ implies $\langle S\rangle\leq H$. So if you know that $a^d\in H$ then you can immediately conclude that $\langle a^d\rangle\leq H$. This is a very useful fact, and you should definitely use it. Taking a general element in $\langle a^d\rangle$ is obviously also correct, but it just complicates the writing.

Comment: @Edd I understood. Thank you

Comment: @Mark How this concept is applied here? As $ a^k \in \langle a^d \rangle$ so $\langle a^k \rangle ≤ \langle a^d \rangle$. That means $\langle a^k \rangle \subseteq \langle a^d \rangle$. Am i thinking correct?

Comment: @MuhammadAfzalSoomro Yes, if $a^k\in\langle a^d\rangle$ then $\langle a^k\rangle\leq\langle a^d\rangle$.

Comment: In general, for a subgroup $H$,  if $g \in H$ then $\langle g\rangle\le H$